# Unable to remove /save from a table on clicking "delete" using Ag Grid Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid-angular

**when I am trying to save i get:**

> button-renderer.component.ts:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stopEditing')
> at ProductsComponent.onSaveButtonClick (products.component.ts:94:11)
> at ButtonRendererComponent.onClick (button-renderer.component.ts:36:19)
> at ButtonRendererComponent_Template_button_click_0_listener (button-renderer.component.ts:10:36)
> at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:13975:16)

**when i try to delete i get:**

> button-renderer.component.ts:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateRowData')

products.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import $ from "jquery";
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import { ButtonRendererComponent } from '../button-renderer.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

productname:string = "";
prodstatus:any;
enableEdit:boolean = false;
api:any;
  frameworkComponents: any;

constructor()
  {
    this.frameworkComponents = {
      buttonRenderer: ButtonRendererComponent,
    }
  }

columnDefs  = [
  { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', editable: true },
  { headerName: 'Quantity', field: 'quantity', editable: true },
  {
    headerName: 'Edit',
    cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
    cellRendererParams: {
   onClick: this.onEditButtonClick.bind(this),
    label: 'Edit'
    },
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Save',
    cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
    cellRendererParams: {
    onClick: this.onSaveButtonClick.bind(this),
    label: 'Save'
    },
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Delete',
    cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
    cellRendererParams: {
    onClick: this.onDeleteButtonClick.bind(this),
    label: 'Delete'
    },
  }
];

rowData:any[]=[
  
  {
"name":"TV",
"quantity": 5
},
{
  "name":"phone",
  "quantity": 10
  }

]
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
onGridReady(params) {
  this.api = params.api;
}
  addProduct(value:string){
    // console.log("productname is"+value);
  this.productname = value; 
  this.prodstatus = "Product has been added"
  }

  enableEditMethod(e: any,i: any){
    this.enableEdit = true;

  }

onEditButtonClick(params:any)
{
 this.api.startEditingCell({
    rowIndex: params.rowIndex,
    colKey: 'name'
  });
}

onSaveButtonClick(_params:any)
{
 this.api.stopEditing();
}

onDeleteButtonClick(params:any)
{
this.api.updateRowData({remove: [params.rowData]});
}
```

Html:

`<ag-grid-angular style="width: 800px; height: 800px;" class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowData]="rowData" [editType]="'fullRow'"  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus] = true> </ag-grid-angular>`

button-renderer-component.ts

```
`// Author: T4professor

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { setAriaRowIndex } from 'ag-grid-community/dist/lib/utils/aria';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-renderer',
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="onClick($event)">{{label}}</button>
    `
})

export class ButtonRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

  params: any;
  label: string | undefined;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.label = this.params.label || null;
  }

  refresh(params?: any): boolean {
    return true;

- onClick($event: any) {
    if (this.params.onClick instanceof Function) {
      // put anything into params u want pass into parents component
      const params = {
        event: $event,
        rowData: this.params.node.rowData
      }
      this.params.onClick(this.params);
    }

  }
}`
```

How to resolve this save and delete issue?`

followed this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-bq5yev?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The error messages point to `this.api` being undefined. Have you checked, if `this.api` is defined at the needed locations?

Comment: I have this in my componens ts file api:any; @Geshode

Comment: @Geshode I have followed this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-bq5yev?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got the example from, but it's a fairly old version. In the current version, there is no such method as updateRowData (see added image)

I won't do more than that. You merely need to follow the documentation a bit more closely. You will learn more when you try out things. If you absolutely can't do it, I might try to help out further when I see what you tried so far.

[image]

---

Well, you didn't quite check the example. Each Angular instance of the Table actually exposes the API via the gridReady Emitter.

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 800px; height: 800px;" class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" (<-- this here) [editType]="'fullRow'" (rowEditingStopped)="onRowEditingStopped"
  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

---

```
onGridReady(params) {
  this.api = params.api;
}
```

And with this you get access to the api.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: params.api.updateRowData is not a function
    at ProductsComponent.onDeleteButtonClick (products.component.ts:128:12)
    at ButtonRendererComponent.onClick (button-renderer.component.ts:36:19)
    at ButtonRendererComponent_Template_button_click_0_listener (button-renderer.component.ts:10:36)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:13975:16)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:14008:22)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.mjs:457:38)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)getting this error @ak.leimrey

Comment: Can you please tell me why i am getting the above issue even after making the necessary changes? @ak.leimrey

Comment: @user21869133 The current version of AgGrid is 29.3.0 but your example is 23.x.x ... changes in the API have been made a looong time ago, so I don't know where you got that example from. So as the error suggests, it might not be part of the API anymore.